# Why does my list stay empty despite adding elements using a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the following:
- check if the element from one list exists in another list. If so, do nothing, if not append it to that list.

Simplefied example code:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[2,3,4]

for item in x:
    if item in y=='False':
        y.append(item)
    else:
        continue
print(y)
```

Unfortunately it does not work and as a beginner I'm not sure why. Any thoughts?

Comment: `if item not in y:`? Could you expand on what exactly you mean by *"does not work"*?

Comment: What do you want to do with `if item in y=='False':` ?

Comment: This: `if item in y=='False':` is wrong

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your code doesn't work, is that the statement:

```
if item in y=='False':
```

checks if the boolean answer of the condition

```
item in y
```

is equal to the string `'False'` for it to trigger the **`if`** block.

---

Based on your question, the code correction should be:

```
if item not in y:
    y.append(item)
```

In the above example, the **`if`** block is entered when there is an item in **`x`** that is ***not*** present in list **`y`**

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[2,3,4]

for item in x:
    if item not in y:
        y.append(item)
    else:
        continue
print(y)
```

Gives:

```
[2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[2,3,4]

for item in x:
    if item not in y:
        y.append(item)
    else:
        continue
print(y)
```

The line: `if item in y=='False':` will never be true because if an item is not in y, it will return the boolean False, not the string 'False'